# Specify VSTSAgent Environment name in ARM template

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

We are migrating our Deployment Group to Pipelines->Environment.
I'd like to know what is the correct parameter name to pass the Environment name to VSTS Agent.

Right now we have :

```
          "VSTSAccountName": "[parameters('VSTSAccount')]",
          "TeamProject": "[parameters('VSTSTeamProject')]",
          "DeploymentGroup": "[parameters('VSTSDeployGroupRedhat')]"
```

I'd like to replace DeploymentGroup with Environment. However, the parameter name is not recognized :

Error message: "Incorrect VSTS account credentials"

Comment: i guess i will have to do it with custom script extension in arm

Comment: Hi FF123; can you give a little bit more detail? Are those parameters being used in a particular pipeline task for example, or in some other way?